# How to specify a source set for a module properly?

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin

I have a base module where I store common resources. But when I try to use these resources in my main module without full package name (e.g com.company.module.main.R.sourcename) I get compile time errors. So I added this code into my main module's gradle:

```
sourceSets {
        main {
            res.srcDirs = ['../base/src/main/res/values/strings.xml', '../base/src/main/res/values-en/strings.xml', 'src/main/res']
        }
```

But this time I can't add anything into main module's res folder. Android Studio shows a popup with error message: *Cannot find resource directory for module Module: 'main'*